# Changing the highlight color of text in Flash with ActionScript 2

Tags: flash, text, actionscript-2

I've got several input text fields, and my design requirement is to have gold text on a black background that, when highlighted, is black text on a gold background; however, Flash's default selected text highlight color scheme is white text on a black background and there is no way to change this.

Does anyone have any workarounds that are easy to implement and don't require additional classes (the design requests minimal outside classes).

Answer (score 0):

in flash player 8 and lower, there is absolutely no way to do that, since the text API is totally limited ... in AS3 for flash player 9, you could kind of try to hack it with `TextField::getCharBoundaries` or so, requireing a lot of code ...
AS3 text layout framework based on flash player 10 text engine would be the easiest way to go ...

so yeah, either change the requirements, or the target and language version ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: I'd love to move to AS3, but the software we're running the Flash movie through only supports AS2. Looks like I'm going to use the "lots of code" solution.